# what are the risks when mixing different DELL servers and how to know supported rhel versions

Tags: redhat, dell, central-processing-unit, intel

we are using the following DELL servers and this server is part of the cluster

SERVER - **R730**

we want to add new servers as `R740` to our cluster ( `R740` is with Intel `Xeon Silver 4110 8c Processor`)

so regarding that we have 2 question

how to know the supported rhel versions for this new HW - `R740`

can we mix both HW as R730 and R740 ?

Comment: You read the manufacturer's documentation.

Comment: unfortunately , we not found the doc

Comment: then Ask dell, they have a great support Hotline in case you bought it, hopefully

Comment: OS Support matrix: https://linux.dell.com/files/supportmatrix/RHEL_Support_Matrix.pdf